# (Extended) Proximity Analysis on QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, proximity

I have a road shapefile that I've rasterized. My study area goes beyond where the roads are.

I've tried using Proximity tool with the rasterized roads to create a "euclidean distance" layer (similar to ArcGIS). However, it only extends until the extent of the rasterized roads.

I need it to extend further to fill my study area. How do I do this on QGIS?

Comment: The output should be the same size as the input, it is likely that when you rasterized your roads the output raster was exactly the extent of the input lines. this might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92460/how-to-set-the-output-extents-of-rasterization-in-qgis

Comment: Just increase the extent when you [rasterize](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#gdalrasterize) i.e. use the output extent parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly understand what you want. But if I understand correctly you need a raster file which have roads and your working area borders.

I think you need to merge 2 different vector layer (roads layer and working area border layer) after that you can use "Rasterize" function.

1- If roads layer geometry type is line, you can convert as polygon geometry type with "Buffer" function.(Vector/Geoprocessing Tools)

2-After you can use "Difference" function to get clipped border polygon.
(Vector/Geoprocessing Tools)

[image]

3-Use "Merge vector layers" function to marge "clipped working border polygon" and buffered roads layer.(Vector/Data Management Tools)

4- Use Rasterize function for result layer.
[image]